# How can I build cannon.js source code to get cannon.js lib

Tags: cannon.js

The cannon.js project is in github url: https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js

But I cannot find anyways to build this source code to get cannon.js library in binary folder.

Can you tell me the way to build this source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have git, [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/), and [grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) installed.

On the command line, do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js.git;
cd cannon.js;
npm install;
grunt;
```